# MATLAB questions?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions

There are a lot of questions marked as "off-topic" in the subject, the majority are the newest ones. matlab is a tag of **mathematics** and there is no subject in **stackexange** exclusivelly for this topic. Why are then all matlab question marked as off-topic? Could anyone help me find a suitable place to ask?

There are a lot of good questions (not extrictly mathematical) with that tag
(see [Matlab wrong cube root](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1049421/378968)). And there are questions answered which require good math skills. I don't think is correct to mark them as "off-topic".

Comment: Related older posts: [Is MATLAB on-topic? (reprise)](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11471) and [Is matlab on topic](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1182).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) and [several other sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tagged/matlab%22+site:stackexchange.com) also have matlab tag. Stack Overflow is also explicitly mentioned [in the tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/matlab/info) for the ([tag:matlab]) tag.

Comment: The easy rule of thumb is to ask yourself, is the question a programming question or a mathematical question? The former is off-topic and the latter should be judged on a case-by-case basis. Of course there are borderline questions, which is why not everything is black or white. Mostly gray. Or grey, if you're British.